# Mistake on Nodejitsu | Need to connect to API

Tags: host, nodejitsu

By accident, I entered the command `$ jitsu host jit.su` .

Now, I can't even login with commandline. The following message appears:

`The Nodejitsu-API requires you to connect the Nodejitsu's stack (api.nodejitsu.com)`

What does that mean and how can I revert the situation?

Answer (score 1):

Command line to fix the problem: `$ jitsu host api.nodejistu.com`